# Postgresql multi-column GIN index

Tags: postgresql, gin-index

Suppose a postgresql table `items` like this. (`keywords` column is of type `text[]`)

```
name   account_id      keywords
------------------------------
foo1   1               ['k1', 'k2']
foo2   1               ['k1', 'k3']
foo3   2               ['k4', 'k1']
foo4   2               ['k1', 'k6']
```

Each row in items is relate to a `Account` (the table is virtually splitted by account_id). We want make queries like: "items for account 1 with keyword k1". This query requires a composite GIN index on `account_id` and `keywords` column.

Actually, we need an inverted index, with rows like this: (the key for each row should be composite)

`(account_id, keyword) --> [item1, item2, ...]`

What's the right way to create this index in postgresql?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is same as the answer for this question: [Inner join using an array column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39082)

The main point is installing the `btree_gin` extension (this may require additional package, like `postgresql-contrib`)

Then, the extension can be enabled easily with: (requires postgresql >= 9.1)

`CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;`

And index can be created with:

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON items USING GIN (account_id, keywords);`