# Best query to exclude existing friends from query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a User table

```
/ id_user / username / ..
```

friends table (pair AB and BA):

```
/ friend_of / friend_to
```

and a friend_request table (used for pending friend requests)

```
/ id_req/ sent_from / sent_to
```

I would like to have a little search for new friend feature (autosuggestion style) and I would like NOT to show in the list friends that are ALREADY in my friends list OR being in a friend request pending.

The idea behind the query would be to show the username of user NOT in the friend_to column and NOT in the sent_to column.

I came up with these two flavors:

```
select id_user,username 
from public.user u 
where 
username like '%tom%' 
and 
u.id_user NOT IN (SELECT sent_to FROM friend_request where sent_from = 288) 
AND 
u.id_user NOT IN (SELECT friend_to FROM friends where friend_of=288);
```

OR

```
select id_user,username
from public.user u 
left join friend_request fr 
on 
u.id_user=sent_to AND fr.sent_from=288
left join friends f 
on 
u.id_user = f.friend_to AND f.friend_of=288
where username like '%tom%' AND sent_to IS NULL and friend_to IS NULL;
```

Both of these produce the same result. But I would like some advice on which one is a better choice performance and bets practice wise?

Comment: Efficiency and execution plans depend on the DBMS. Which one are you using?

Comment: The db is PostreSQL

Comment: Questions for performance optimisation need proper information like instructed here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` is typically the slowest option. `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` is more promising. Or `NOT EXISTS`:

- [Select rows where value of second column is not present in first column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16650/help-with-this-select-in-the-same-table/16651#16651)

#### Query

Just your query, formatted:

```
SELECT u.id_user, u.username
FROM   "user" u 
LEFT   JOIN friend_request fr ON fr.sent_to = u.id_user
                             AND fr.sent_from = 288
LEFT   JOIN friends f ON f.friend_to = u.id_user
                     AND f.friend_of = 288
WHERE  u.username LIKE '%tom%'
AND    fr.sent_to IS NULL
AND    f.friend_to IS NULL;
```

Or, a variant with [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) anti-semi-joins:

```
SELECT u.id_user, u.username
FROM   "user" u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM friend_request
   WHERE  sent_to = u.id_user
   AND    sent_from = 288
   ) 
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM friends
   WHERE  friend_to = u.id_user
   AND    friend_of = 288
   )
WHERE  u.username LIKE '%tom%';
```

#### Indexes

The most important factor for performance. An ideal setup would have:

1. A **trigram GIN or GiST index** on `"user".username`. You need the additional module [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html). Instructions - and Gin or GiST?

   - [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

   If **index-only scans** are possible, append the otherwise useless `id_user`. You need the additional module `btree_gin` (or `btree_gist` respectively):

   - [Inner join using an array column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39082/inner-join-using-an-array-column/39135#39135)

   Then:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX usr_trgm_idx ON "user" USING gin (username gin_trgm_ops, id_user);
   ```
2. Multicolumn indexes (or a UNIQUE / PK constraint) on **`(sent_from, sent_to)`** and **`(friend_of, friend_to)`** - with columns in *that order*. The reversed order would work, too, but not quite as good. Each query checks for a *single* `friend_of` combined with *many different* `friend_to`, which is faster with the suggested column order, because this way tuples are much rather **localized on the same or a few index pages**.

That said, the proof of the pudding is still in the eating.
Get the final verdict from [`EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) in your production database.

#### Aside

Do **not** call your table `user`, that's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).